# How to export bin ranges to python macros so that pandas variables can be scored?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel table which has 4 columns - Index, Bin, WoR, feature_name. The table shows the Bin ranges and the weight of evidence (WoE) for several variables var1 to varn.

I have imported the excel into a pandas dataframe and would like to extract the lower and upper limits into separate columns as shown in the table below. I wrote the code below to perform this function. However I get 98.5 and 99.5 for lower_limit and upper_limit respectively. So this code is not working. Any suggestions where I might be doing it wrong?

The final goal of this exercise is to automatically generate python code which has list of macros (def) to bin the variables. If there is a better approach, I would like to hear that as well.

```
model_vars = ['var1','var2']
binned_vars = ['var1','var2',....'varn']
for variable in model_vars:
    if variable in binned_vars:
        print(variable)
        bin_list = df_bin_edges[df_bin_edges['feature_name'] == variable]['Bin'].to_list()
        for bin_range in bin_list:
            if (bin_range != 'Special') or (bin_range != 'Missing'):
#                 print(bin_range)
                extract_bin_list = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", bin_range)
#                 print(extract_bin_list)
                if df_bin_edges[(df_bin_edges['Bin'] == bin_range) & (df_bin_edges['feature_name'] == variable)]['Index'].to_list()[0]==0:
                    df_bin_edges['lower_limit'] = '-99999990'
                    df_bin_edges['upper_limit'] = extract_bin_list[0]
                elif (df_bin_edges[(df_bin_edges['Bin'] == bin_range) & (df_bin_edges['feature_name'] == variable)]['Index'].to_list()[0]==0) & (len(extract_bin_list) == 1):
                    df_bin_edges['upper_limit'] = '99999990'
                    df_bin_edges['lower_limit'] = extract_bin_list[0]
                elif (len(extract_bin_list) == 2):
                    df_bin_edges[['lower_limit','upper_limit']] = extract_bin_list
            elif (bin_range == 'Special'):
                df_bin_edges[['lower_limit','upper_limit']] = ['-999999999','-999999999']
            elif (bin_range == 'Missing'):
                df_bin_edges[['lower_limit','upper_limit']] = ['','']
df_bin_edges.head()
```

| Index | Bin | WoE | feature_name | how_to_extract_lower_limit | how_to_extract_lupper_limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [-inf, 1.50) | 1.363071258 | var1 | -999999990 | 1.50 |
| 1 | [1.50, 2.50) | 1.231135161 | var1 | 1.50 | 2.50 |
| 2 | [2.50, 3.50) | 0.819430598 | var1 | 2.50 | 3.50 |
| 3 | [3.50, 4.50) | 0.617398733 | var1 | 3.50 | 4.50 |
| 4 | [4.50, 14.50) | 0.507075641 | var1 | 4.50 | 14.50 |
| 5 | [14.50, 15.50) | -0.627789607 | var1 | 14.50 | 15.50 |
| 6 | [15.50, 20.50) | -0.706258537 | var1 | 15.50 | 20.50 |
| 7 | [20.50, inf) | -0.950134462 | var1 | 20.50 | 999999990 |
| 8 | Special | 0 | var1 | -999999999 | -999999999 |
| 9 | Missing | 0 | var1 | np.Nan | np.Nan |
| 0 | [-inf, 41.50) | 0.961019117 | var2 | -999999990 | 41.50 |
| 1 | [41.50, 108.50) | 0.360937878 | var2 | 41.5 | 108.50 |
| 2 | [108.50, 669.50) | 0.159048336 | var2 | 108.5 | 669.50 |
| 3 | [669.50, 1396.50) | -0.403814421 | var2 | 669.5 | 1396.50 |
| 4 | [1396.50, 1921.50) | -0.491165728 | var2 | 1396.5 | 1921.50 |
| 5 | [1921.50, inf) | -0.539465215 | var2 | 1921.5 | 999999990 |
| 6 | Special | 0.837004951 | var2 | -999999999 | -999999999 |
| 7 | Missing | 0 | var2 | np.Nan | np.Nan |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Series.replace` to reformat `Bin` column:

```
>>> df['Bin'].replace({'Special': '-999999999, -999999999',
                       'Missing': 'NaN, NaN',
                       '-inf': '-999999990',
                       'inf': '999999990',
                       '\[': '', '\)': ''}, regex=True) \
             .str.split(',') \
             .apply(pd.Series) \
             .astype(float) \
             .rename(columns={0: 'lower_limit', 1: 'upper_limit'})

    lower_limit  upper_limit
0  -999999990.0          1.5
1           1.5          2.5
2           2.5          3.5
3           3.5          4.5
4           4.5         14.5
5          14.5         15.5
6          15.5         20.5
7          20.5  999999990.0
8  -999999999.0 -999999999.0
9           NaN          NaN
10 -999999990.0         41.5
11         41.5        108.5
12        108.5        669.5
13        669.5       1396.5
14       1396.5       1921.5
15       1921.5  999999990.0
16 -999999999.0 -999999999.0
17          NaN          NaN
```

Comment: @Zenvega, If you prefer to have `str` instead of `float` you can remove `.astype(float)`.

Comment: Thanks so much. your solution works. This is exactly what I want.